# JS print 0 - 99 or 99 - 0 in order

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout, event-loop

all. I'm new to JS. Here I met a JS question showed below:

```
function print(n) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(n);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
}
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    print(i);
}
```

The requirement is:

1. You need to change the program to make it print 0-99 or 99-0 in order;
2. You cannot use global variables;
3. You can only change the code inner setTimeout;
4. You cannot modify `Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000`.

Here I get some solutions for this question, but there are some of these answers I don't understand, so I hope you guys can help me why this can work. I understand the answers for the first one, the second one and the last one, but I am not quite clear why the rest of the answer can work. Especially for the third one, if I remove the code `return ()=>{}`, the code still works but it will report an error `100Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src <URL> <URL> 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https:".`.

```
//1.
function print1(n) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(n);
    }, 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
}

// 2. 
function print2(n) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(i--);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
}

// 3.
function print3(n) {
    setTimeout((() => {
        console.log(n)
        return () => { }
    }).call(n, []), Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
}
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    print(i);
}

//4.
function print4(n) {

    setTimeout(() => {

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(n);
        }, 1000 * n);

    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
}

// 5. 
function print5(n) {
    setTimeout((() => {
        console.log(n);
    })(), Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting problem... Learned a lot from this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third approach essentially calls a function as soon as the `setTimeout` line runs, *before the timeout callback runs*. So when `print(i);` is called, the number is logged *immediately*, before the next iteration of the loop starts.

Functionally, it's similar to this:

```
function print3(n) {
    console.log(n);
    setTimeout(<unimporant>);
}
```

It works because the function inside the timeout is invoked immediately with the `.call`:

```
setTimeout((() => {
    console.log(n)
    return () => { }
}).call(n, []),
```

simplifies to

```
setTimeout((() => {
    console.log(n)
    return () => { }
})(),
```

which is basically just

```
console.log(n)
setTimeout((() => {
    return () => { }
})(),
```

or, substituting the returned function from the IIFE:

```
console.log(n)
setTimeout(() => {},
```

The callback passed to `setTimeout` doesn't do anything.

> if I remove the code return ()=>{}, the code still works but it will report an error

It sounds like you returned a string instead of the function at the end, which will result in the interpreter trying to run the string. While it's *possible* to do such a thing in some environments, it's basically the same thing as `eval`.

```js
setTimeout('console.log("never do this");');
```

which is why the warning comes up.

Comment: Just for curiosity, Is it possible to print `0-100` with all conditions applied by OP.

Comment: OP has included in their question a number of possible approaches, which (as it seems to be implied) satisfy the requirements. The `print4` looks like the best approach here, if this is an assignment, I wouldn't be certain if a grader would count an IIFE (as used in the other approaches) as permitted without asking for clarification (and `print2` relies on a global, and `print1` requires inserting an additional parameter in the middle)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array(num) to make an empty array of length num.
then you can use .fill(n), to fill all the array index's with n.
Then you can use, .map() to loop through the array and return new values to replace the value we used in .fill() .

```js
function range(start, end) {
    // checks that the end number is bigger than the start number.
    // this is because it should decrement instead of increment if the end is smaller.
    if(end > start){
        return Array(end - start).fill(0).map((_, i) => start + i)
    } else {
        return Array(start - end).fill(0).map((_, i) => start - i)
    }
}
```

You can use parts of the function i made to do what you want. To print all of the values just do console.log(...arrayName), or loop through it with .forEach() and print them.